# inheritance from base class

Tags: c#

I have aquestion about objects and their ability to call a method from parent and child classes.

Base class has a method(). In the main, I have objectFromBaseClass and objectFromChildClass. Can both objects have access to method() from the base class?

I am trying  to grasp the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as method() is not declared as private, yes.  If method(), as you have defined, is declared private, then only the base class can access it .  If method is declared protected, then the base class and all derived class can access it.  If method is declared internal, then it can be accessed within the same Assembly(dll).  If method is declared public, then it can be accessed everywhere.

Comment: It's somewhat more complicated than that.  If the method is declared `protected`, then a method in the derived class can call that protected method on an instance of the derived class only.  It cannot call that protected method on an instance of the base class, or other classes derived from the same base class.

Answer (score 2):

Follow [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

these links will clear your doubt regarding accessibilty of members.

> you should make method() protected or public to access in both parent
>   and child class. private methods are accessible inside the class in
>   which they are created/ declared.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As Bojin Li said, unless there is an access modifier like 'private' declared before your method, all classes that inherit from the method's base class will have the "method()" member.

By default, class members without the 'public' access modifier are considered private.

Two things to keep in mind (that I haven't seen mentioned by others already) are that if said "method()" is 'static', it can be accessed at any time and there is no need to inherit from its class to gain "method()", also you can only inherit from ONE class at a time in C#.